# Iphone app to be used like usb storage.

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios4, local-storage

I'm wanting to access applications storage via iTunes, where i can save documents and be available in my app.

I have looked all over google, but without a specific name i don't know what I'm looking for.

Some of the app's that use this functionality are VLC & usb Disk; there are many many more.

So I'm asking what the API is called and if anyone knows of sample code or an example.

Comment: On Jailbroken devices, you can actually make a partition *on* the i{Pod, Phone} and have it show up as a USB drive. Extremely useful IMO, but too bad Apple doesn't let untouched iOS devices do that...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Essentially, all you have to do is add a boolean `UIFileSharingEnabled` (YES) key to your app's info.plist. Then the documents added through iTunes will be available in your app's documents directory.

> UIFileSharingEnabled (Boolean - iOS) specifies whether the application
>   shares files through iTunes. If this key is YES, the application
>   shares files. If it is not present or is NO, the application does not
>   share files. Applications must put any files they want to share with
>   the user in their /Documents directory, where
>    is the path to the application’s home directory.
>
> In iTunes, the user can access an application’s shared files from the
>   File Sharing section of the Apps tab for the selected device. From
>   this tab, users can add and remove files from the directory.

This key is supported in iOS 3.2 and later.

Apple's sample code: [DocInteraction](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/DocInteraction/Introduction/Intro.html)